# Unable to compare 2 integer variables in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, comparison

I have this following piece of code where I am basically trying to compare 2 integers in a batch file (one of them is retrieved from registry) -

```
set mainCounter=1
reg add HKLM\Software\Looptest /f /v mainCounter1 /t REG_SZ /d 0

rem ---- some code here ---

FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "mainCounter1"') do set "mainCounter1=%%b"
echo mainCounter :: %mainCounter%
echo mainCounter1 :: %mainCounter1%

if %mainCounter% EQU %mainCounter1% goto _reImageSystem

:_reImageSystem
echo mainCounter while reimaging :: %mainCounter%
echo mainCounter1 while reimaging :: %mainCounter1%
pause
```

This code clearly suggests that, value of mainCounter is 1 (set manually)
And,
The value of mainCounter1 is set to registry.. which is 0.
Still , when I compare `if %mainCounter% EQU %mainCounter1% goto _reImageSystem` , clearly it should not go inside  _reImageSystem, but it goes...

The output is:

```
mainCounter :: 1
mainCounter1 :: 0
mainCounter while reimaging :: 1
mainCounter1 while reimaging :: 0
```

So, possible the comparison is not working..

```
if %mainCounter% EQU %mainCounter1% goto _reImageSystem
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to remember that batch files are sequential processing.  If you don't want a line to process you need to branch away from it or use some other nested conditional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comparison is false it will still *fall through* to the label and execute.

To prevent this branch away:

```
if %mainCounter% EQU %mainCounter1% goto _reImageSystem
goto end

:_reImageSystem
bla bla
bla bla

:end
```

(Or `GOTO:eof` to end or invert your logic and use `NEQ`)

Comment: Another option: an `else` clause: `if %mainCounter% EQU %mainCounter1% (goto _reImageSystem) else goto :EOF`